# Returning the first day of a given month in weekday format with PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

So I want, for the purpose of creating a calendar, to identify what the first weekday of any given month is.  I have the following code:

```
    $today=date('Y-m-d');

    IF (!$_GET) {
    $now=time();
    }
    ELSE {
    $now=strtotime($_GET['month']);
    }

    // the month in question is linked through a GET form variable in the Ymd format

    $thisdaynow=date('Y-m-d', $now);

    $monthyear=date('F Y', $now);

    $thismonth=date('M', $now);

    $thisyear=date('Y', $now);

    $weekday=date('l', $now);

    $firstday = new DateTime($thisdaynow);
    $firstday->modify('first day of this month');
    $work=$firstday->format('Ymd');
    $firstweekday=date('l', $work);
    $firstdayweek=date('w', $work);

    ECHO 'Today is '.$thisdaynow.'<br />';

    ECHO 'The first day of the month was '.$work.'<br />';

    ECHO 'Today is a '.$weekday.'.<br />';

    ECHO 'The first day of this month was a '.$firstweekday.', the '.$firstdayweek.'th day of the week.<br />';
```

this returns:

> Today is 2013-05-06
>
> The first day of the month was 20130501
>
> Today is a Monday.
>
> The first day of this month was a Saturday, the 6th day of the week.
>
> There are 31 days this month.

Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry, but your code is really convoluted. What is $_GET['month']? A string with the month name? An integer with the month number? Is it always the current year? What is wrong with new DateTime("First weekday of June 2013")? etc.

Comment: This should be a comment. I agree his code is messy, but in the code he states that the $_GET['month'] is a variable in Ymd format.

Comment: @mattedgod well, the first day of May was a Wednesday, so I expect 'The first day of this month was a Wednesday, the 4th day of the week,' the rest is correct which is why I am pretty baffled.

Comment: @edwardmp that has no impact on the problem, thanks for your input

Comment: I know it doesn't have impact but it is neater and convention.

Comment: this is actually snipped from all over the code, but these are all the parts to do with the dates, all the various individual date variables I have are used for something elsewhere in the program.

I stated that $_GET['month'] comes from a form on another page in the Ymd format, ie 20130606

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$inputMonth = '2013-05-01';
$month = date("m" , strtotime($inputMonth));
$year = date("Y" , strtotime($inputMonth));
$getdate = getdate(mktime(null, null, null, $month, 1, $year));
echo $getdate["weekday"];
```

Produces:
Wednesday

If problem persists.
Problem might be here:

```
IF (!$_GET) {
```

Should be

```
if (!isset($_GET['month'])) {
```

This way, you are always assigning to current `time()` which is why the first day of month is always of the current month.

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4ja-928

Comment: Mine also produces Saturday.  Then when I check for May - Saturday.  And July - Saturday.

Comment: Tested with May and June and produces Wednesday and Saturday. Test my code please.

Comment: it looks to work fine, any way to format $getdate as a numerical 0-6 (sunday being 0)?  that is honestly more important to the code than getting the name of the day.

Comment: I suspected at first the !$_GET thing, but $now is correctly set in my original code, so that's not the issue.  thank you for your codesnip though, I will have to jump through some hoops to get a numerical weekday but its better than staring at my original code all day.

Comment: You might want to check again. Use $getdate['wday'] for numerical weekday check for more info http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php

Comment: You know the problem is somewhere else as I stated. My code works. Is your serverdate correctly?

Comment: it is a local install of xampp, it is in line with my PC's clock.  I've already restarted the page, thank you for all your time, I will use your method from the beginning this time and hopefully it will work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31289/discussion-between-edwardmp-and-chodo-baggins)

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
$m = 1;
$d = 1;
$y = 2013;

do {
    $time = strtotime($y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d);
    $month = date('F',$time);
    $dayOfMonth = date('l',$time);
    $totalDays = date('t',$time);
    echo 'First day of '.$month.', '.$y.' is '.$dayOfMonth.' 
          ('.$totalDays.' days in '.$month.').<br />';
} while (++$m < 13);
```

Will display these results:

```
First day of January, 2013 is Tuesday (31 days in January).
First day of February, 2013 is Friday (28 days in February).
First day of March, 2013 is Friday (31 days in March).
First day of April, 2013 is Monday (30 days in April).
First day of May, 2013 is Wednesday (31 days in May).
First day of June, 2013 is Saturday (30 days in June).
First day of July, 2013 is Monday (31 days in July).
First day of August, 2013 is Thursday (31 days in August).
First day of September, 2013 is Sunday (30 days in September).
First day of October, 2013 is Tuesday (31 days in October).
First day of November, 2013 is Friday (30 days in November).
First day of December, 2013 is Sunday (31 days in December).
```

Lots more info in the PHP manual at: http://php.net/date

Comment: I honestly can not see where my code varies from this in function.